# What's the name for this JavaScript pattern?

Tags: javascript

I've been using this pattern whenever I need to create a class that might need to be instantiated multiple times and I want to prevent private methods from being accessed outside of the object.

What's the name for this JavaScript pattern?

http://jsfiddle.net/CHcXG/

```
var baseball = (function() {

    var _add = function(value) {
         value = value + 5;
         return value;
    };


    var constructor = function(iVal) {
       this.baseball = true;
       this.num = iVal; 
    };

    constructor.prototype.add = function() {
         this.num = _add(this.num);
    };

    return constructor;

})();

var test = new baseball(5);
var testb = new baseball(6);
```

The names, values and methods in the example above are completely meaningless; I just want to illustrate the syntax, structure, and usage of the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript), almost a [revealing module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript).  See the linked pages by Addy Osmani for information about it and many other useful Javascript design patterns.

Comment: The module pattern is nearly identical to my example, but it looks like the module pattern is only instantiated once--since it returns an object rather than a prototyped function.

Answer (score 0):

yes, module pattern, but is also borderline revealer pattern.

i guess it could be considered the "[revealer module pattern](http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-programming-patterns/#revealing)" if you wanted to be generous with there only being 1 single return function